# Append Hidden input fields and bind them to the Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm usinge a 3rd Party file uploader(Backload)to upload images & JavaScript to get the uploaded image names.I want to bind that list of Image Names into my MVC model. My requirement is to create hidden inputs dynamically when I submit the form. I know , I have to use sequential binding here with a loop. Can anyone help me how to use proper syntax to achieve this. 
It should be something similar to this

```c#
for (int i= 0; i< noOfImages; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="Model.Images[i].Name"  value=file.name />
}
```

(please note that I don't want Ajax solution for this and please show me code to use in my Razor view or if there is another better solution please let me know).Thanks.

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ImageModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public virtual ItemModel Items { get; set; }
}
```

I use following JavaScript code to get the values of Uploaded File Name and to create hidden inputs when I click submit button of #ItemCreate form.

```
$('#ImageUplodedtable input[name="ImageName"]').each(function () {
    $('#ItemCreateForm').append('<input  name="ImageName" value="' + this.value + '"/>');
```

I'm adding the below part to my question. I missed single quotes and two plus signs ['+i+'] now it's working fine.

```
  $('#ImageUplodedtable input[name="ImageName"]').each(function () {
    for (int i= 0; i< noOfImages; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="Images[+'i'+].Name"  value="' + this.value + '" />
}
```

I can't use .each() with for loop here.Can anyone suggest a way to get all the Image Names in Uploded table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done it right in your for loop at the top, but once you get to the JavaScript portion, you're bungling the names. Keep the names of the input in the same style as the first for loop and you'll be fine, i.e. `Images[N].Name` where `N` is the index of the item in the collection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

$('#ImageUplodedtable input[name="ImageName"]').each(function (){
 for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
 $('#AddItem').append('<input  name="Images[i].Name" value="' + this.value + '"/>');
         }
I tried this but for loop's Increment value (i) not working correctly.( <input name="Images[0].Name /> is working without for loop. Could you pls let me know why Increment value is not working here.

Comment: Because `i` starts as 0 and your condition states that it must be less than 1. Therefore, the for loop runs once, where `i` then gets incremented to 1 and no longer satisfies the condition.

Comment: Sorry , I haven't explained my problem clearly in my last comment.
I manually gave name="Images[0].Name as input's name (Without for loop)to check whether model binding working or not. It works fine.
But when I use FOR loop it's not working. Assume I have one Image name and  when for loop runs once, It should create <input name=Images[0].Name /> but i value remains as i... name=Images[i].name . That's my problem. (Is it OK to use .each() with for loop? )

Comment: really sorry, It was my mistake. wrong syntax.
name="Images['+i+']

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use this function to create hidden files. I hope this may help a newbie like me in the future .

```
function CretaeHiddenFields(){
var uploadedImages = $('#ImageUplodedtable input[name="ImageName"]') ;
var divArea = $(#CreateInputDiv);
    for (var i = 0; i < uploadedImages .length; i++) {
        var imageName = document.createElement("input");           
        imageName.type = "hidden";
        imageName.name = "Images[" + i + "].Name";
        imageName.value = uploadedImage[i].value; // value of #ImageUplodedtable ImageNameinputs
        formCreteItm.append(imageName);

    }

}
```